# ValueError: X has 3 features, but LinearSVC is expecting 64852 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, svm, text-classification

I get the following error when I try to deploy this model.

```
ValueError: X has 3 features, but LinearSVC is expecting 64852 features as input
```

Example of data below.

```
data = [[3409, False, 'Lorum Ipsum'], [0409, True, 'dolor sit amet consectetuer'], [7869, False, 'Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'booleanv', 'text']
```

The code where the model gets created below.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

df = pd.read_csv('cleandata.csv')

# Split dataset into training and validation set
train_size = int(df.shape[0] * 0.8)

train_df = df[:train_size]
val_df = df[train_size:]

# split text and labels
X_train = train_df.text.to_numpy()
Y_train = train_df.booleanv.to_numpy()
X_test = val_df.text.to_numpy()
Y_test = val_df.booleanv.to_numpy()


tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1))
X_train_tf = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_tf = tfidf.transform(X_test)

model1 = LinearSVC(random_state=0, tol=1e-5)
model1.fit(X_train_tf, Y_train)

import pickle

pickle.dump(model1, open('classification.pickle','wb'))
pickle.dump(tfidf, open('vectorizer.pickle','wb'))
```

X_Train and X_Test are both arrays. The input I feed in the API I created is in json format. I suspect that I need to transform my input somehow. Is this correct? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain predictions from your model, you need to follow the same transformation steps that were undertaken during the training phase.

The `ValueError` you are encountering indicates that you are passing raw data to the classifier without vectorization. As the model has been trained on a sparse matrix consisting of 64852 features (the outcome of `tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)` ), it expects a vectorized input with the same number of features. Here is how it can be done:

```
input_data = {
               'id': 1234,  
               'booleanv': False, 
               'text' : 'your input text goes here'
              }

#vectorize 
input_vectorized = tfidf.transform([input_data['text']]) 

#get predictions 
predictions = model.predict(input_vectorized)
```

This can, of course, be modified to work with batches instead of single inputs. Moreover, the use of [pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) is highly recommended to assemble all the different steps.

Comment: Massive thanks! This got me a step further. I now get the following message, so I am going to dive into that now! 

ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.

Comment: My bad! The transform method expects a list (or an iterable), and not a string. I've updated my answer.